How can I create a Firebase security rules function that limit sizes on nested object?
How can I create a Firebase security rules function to enforce the following size constraints, ensuring compliance with minimum requirements as well?
The root-level data object should have at most 2 keys.
Each key inside data can contain at most 12 sub-keys.
Each sub-key (e.g., subId1 to subId12) must be an array, with each array containing at most 7 elements.
How can I write a Firebase security rule function that effectively enforces these constraints while maintaining both maximum and minimum limits on the different levels of the data structure?
also please note that subId1 can be available as well to access the second level.


// Example data structure with constraints
// Size Max 2 (Root level: max 2 keys)
// data: { 
//   Size Max 12 (Second level: max 12 keys)
//   key1: {
//      subId1: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId2: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId3: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId4: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId5: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId6: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId7: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId8: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId9: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId10: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId11: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//      subId12: [], // <------ Size Max of 7 elements
//   },
//   key2: { ... } // Same as above
// },





service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /yourCollection/{document} {
      
      // Defining read and write rules
      allow read, write: if isValidData(request.resource.data);
      
      function isValidData(data) {
        // Ensures the root-level object has at most 2 keys.
        return data.size() <= 2
          // Iterate through each key at the root level.
          && data.keys().hasOnly([
               // Specify the potential key names, assuming they have a limit




Have a look at this  Limit fields written on nested object & limit a size of array of map field content which might help

@SathiAiswarya the issue is that the keys are dynamic

can you check this link1 & link2
